# EFilererror exception in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have registered the package *TMS Unicode Component Pack* in my Delphi 7 containing *TNT components*. 
This package contains a class named `TTntCustomComboBox` which I use to create my own custom component named `Combobox2` :

```
unit Combobox2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, Classes, Graphics, Controls, StdCtrls, ImgList, ActiveX, SysUtils, TntStdCtrls, TntWindows;


type
  TCombobox2 = class(TTntCustomComboBox) 

...
procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Standard', [TCombobox2]);
end;

...
```

I've added this component (`TCombobox2`) to the package `dclusr.dpk`.
Compiling `dclusr.dpk` works but installing the package raises an exception :

***Registration procedure Combobox2.Register in package C:\program files\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl\dclusr.bpl raised an exception class EFilererror : A class named TTntCustomComboBox already exists***

So, how do I fix that ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Could you show more code. The entire declaration of `TComboBox2`, and your `Register` procedure.

Comment: What are the contents of the 'Combobo2.pas' unit (as opposed to 'Combobox2.pas')?

Comment: Sorry, I 've edited the question. You have to read Combobox2, not Combobo2

Comment: `TCombobox2 = class(TTntCustomComboBox)` doesn't compile. What is it really? Is there a semi-colon there?

Comment: Does your package contain a `Register` procedure for the TNT components?

Comment: The package dclusr compiles. It is not a compilation issue. 
TNT components are registered in their own package.

Comment: Yes, it compiles. But does it compile *without warnings*? If you're doing it wrong, then you probably see warnings telling you that various units are being included into your package *implicitly*. Always treat such a warning as an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that your package is trying to register a component that is already registered, namely `TTntCustomComboBox`.

It's not obvious from the details that you have provided why this would happen. One possible reason would be if you included the TNT components in your package instead of referencing that in your package's requires clause. Another possible reason would be if your `Register` function attempted to register `TTntCustomComboBox`. This could happen if your actual declaration of `TCombobox2` was like so:

```
TCombobox2 = TTntCustomComboBox;
```

Answer (score 1):

Put {$WEAKPACKAGEUNIT ON} after unit caption.